# How to list all groups that have CUSTOMER type by Google groups API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I would like to list all groups on my Google domain that has specific "type" is  CUSTOMER.
Does anybody knows about a way to query by fields so the returned list will be filtered?

```
{
    "kind": "admin#directory#members",
    "etag": "\"t3T4wFaZo04vdXaxNQGkK1fzKz4/w4BU1oBly0ZCiFmdIX3OZdWgmsI\"",
    "members": [
        {

             "kind": "admin#directory#member",
             "etag": "\"t3T4wFaZo04vdXaxNQGkK1fzKz4/q8PZ1ZbbaQxYeAB7lQTCQIZeTbc\"",
             "id": "C035o7jwg",
             "role": "MEMBER",
             "type": "CUSTOMER"
        }
    ]
}
```

In older api version:
      feed_url = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/group/2.0/' + google_apps_domain + '/?member=*'

Comment: What is the JSON above for? is it for the group resource? can youplease provide a link to the relevant API reference doc you are referring to in your question